# Custom Dialog Event Handling with Event Tables

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I pretend to "grab" and process the events: EVT_TEXT from wxTextCtrl and EVT_BUTTON from wxID_APPLY.

I try handling the events with Event Tables and I can't? Why?

The source code:

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
   #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class Dialog : public wxDialog
{
    public:
        Dialog(wxWindow *parent, const wxString &title);

    private:
        void OnNameChange(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void OnApply(wxCommandEvent &event);

        wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

        wxTextCtrl *m_name;
};

enum
{
    ID_NAME = 1
};

Dialog::Dialog(wxWindow *parent, const wxString &title) :
    wxDialog(parent, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER)
{
    wxBoxSizer *vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    SetSizer(vbox);

    wxFlexGridSizer *flexGrid = new wxFlexGridSizer(2, 2, 5, 5);

    wxStaticText *label = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "&Name:");
    flexGrid->Add(label);

    m_name = new wxTextCtrl(this, ID_NAME, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER);
    flexGrid->Add(m_name, 1, wxEXPAND);

    label = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "&Description:");
    flexGrid->Add(label);

    m_description = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE);
    flexGrid->Add(m_description, 1, wxEXPAND);

    flexGrid->AddGrowableRow(1, 1);
    flexGrid->AddGrowableCol(1, 1);

    vbox->Add(flexGrid, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 15);

    vbox->Add(CreateSeparatedButtonSizer(wxAPPLY | wxCANCEL), 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);  
}

void Dialog::OnNameChange(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    m_description->AppendText("Hello\n");
}

void Dialog::OnApply(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    m_description->AppendText("Apply\n");
}

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(Dialog, wxDialog)
    EVT_TEXT(ID_NAME, Dialog::OnNameChange)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_APPLY, Dialog::OnApply)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

It's only possible to handle the events dynamically?

```
Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &Dialog::OnNameChange, this, m_name->GetId());
```

Comment: My guess is, that your `ID_NAME = 1` is invalid. Use `ID_NAME = wxID_HIGHEST + 1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as shown absolutely should work. It's not self-contained, so I can't test it, but there must be something else not shown here preventing it from working. Please try to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you still can't isolate the problem yourself.

Comment: I has not able to identify the problem. But the code now is working.